# Shippable Android Continuous Deployment

Tags: android, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, shippable-ci

I am using Shippable for CI purposes but now I want to integrate continuous deployment as well. Shippable allows to build custom java based docker images but I have yet to see an android build image. Does anyone know if this is even possible in Shippable as of now?

Answer (score 1):

while we do not have an official Docker image to build Android projects, some users have successfully built Android projects by installing the necessary packages using shippable.yml. Here is a great example- https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard

If you create an Android image for Docker and want to contribute it, you can open a PR to https://github.com/shippableImages repo. Thanks!